# How to remove AutoForm dropdown list "(Select One)" field?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

I'm working on a Meteor project and I am using the [AutoForm package](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform).
Now I want to remove the **"(Select One)"** field from the select dropdown list in my form. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `firstOption` attribute to specify a label, for example:

```
{{#autoForm id="selectForm" schema=Schemas.Select}}
     {{> afFormGroup name="favoriteYear" options=options firstOption="Please select your favorite year"}}
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
{{/autoForm}}
```

or you can automatically select the first option (without an empty value) by setting the `firstOption` attribute to `false`:

```
{{#autoForm id="selectForm" schema=Schemas.Select}}
     {{> afFormGroup name="favoriteYear" options=options firstOption=false}}
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
{{/autoForm}}
```